# Delete key and pair from Json file

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm trying to delete a key and its pair from a json file . I tried the codes below but nothing triggers or work. Anyone can modify and assist me

```
reda.json file

[{"carl": 33}, {"carl": 55}, {"user": "user2", "id": "21780"}, {"user": "user2"}, {"user": "123"}, {"user": []}, {"user": []}]
```

```
import json

json_data = json.load(open('reda.json'))
k = "carl"
for d in json_data:
    if k in d:
        del d[k]
```

Comment: This does modify json_data.  It isn't clear what you want it to do.  It isn't going to modify the file.  You'd have to write the file in order to change it.

Comment: Oh ok , i got you, so pop wont work too right ?

Comment: @Icezua see the answer below. If you believe it satisfactory, you can accept the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you load a JSON file into Python using `json.load`, it creates a copy of that JSON in Python. When that copy is changed, these changes are not reflected in the file.

So what you need to do is then transfer your changed copy back to the file.

This can be achieved via a method in the same `json` library as you're using, `dump`. Additionally, we need to supply an additional parameter to `open` to specify that we are writing to the file, not just reading.

```
import json

json_data = json.load(open('reda.json'))
k = "carl"
for d in json_data:
    if k in d:
        del d[k]

json.dump(json_data, open('reda.json','w'))
```

###### References

1. [Python 3.11.0 Documentation: json.dump](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump)
2. [Python 3.11.0 Documentation: open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)

Comment: Thank you sir , God bless, it worked, Now i can sleep , been 4 hrs now tryna solve this issue

Comment: @Icezua if you think it helped, accept the answer

Comment: is there anyway we can delete the curly braces? or delete it as an object in whole, because when i run it delete the key and its value leaving the braces over there

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: I mean when i remove the key and value from the json file , curly braces left there in the file, empty curly braces { }